# Add middleware after login in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am using laravel for my web application,in login I am asking for username ,password and I want to check the email of the logged in user is verified or not. If the verified status is 0 I want to sent the error message  to the login page using the verifiedemail named middleware.

route.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth', 'superadmin'], function () {
    Route::resource('/users', 'UserController'); 
});
Route::get('/', function () {
    if (Auth::guest())
        return view('/auth/login');
    else
        return redirect('/tests');
});
Route::resource('/tests', 'TestController');
Route::get('/sites', 'SiteController@index'); 
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
```

Redirectedifauthenticated.php     <--- middleware file

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        return redirect('/home');
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

verifiedemail.php   <--- middleware file

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ( Auth::check() && Auth::user()->isVerifiedEmail() )
    {
        return redirect('/login');
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

kernel.php

```
 protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'superadmin' => 'App\Http\Middleware\SuperAdmin',
        'verifiedemail' => 'App\Http\Middleware\VerifiedEmail',
    ];
}
```

I think these are the files where i have to change but what and where I have to change that's the question for me .please help thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using the default laravel authentication you can add a listener on the `Illuminate\Auth\Events\Attempting` which is fired on every login attempt and do your validation in the listener.

> More about [fired event on Auth](http://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication#events)
>
> More about [event listeners](http://laravel.com/docs/5.3/events#event-subscribers)

Comment: dear, its not an answer of this question.Read the question again.

Comment: I am having LogSuccessfulLogin in my listner for last_login entry so ,i can use that for verifiedemail middleware also right?

Comment: The `Attempting` event will be fired when the user try to log in, `Login` event is fired when the user is actually logged in

Comment: but in handle of LogSuccessfulLogin  how to call the middleware.

Comment: Don't call your middleware, just add the check in your listerner.

Comment: on logAuthenticated i checking the verified_email==0 if true then i have to call the logout and send the message that  email is not verified. how can i manualy logout the user and how to send the message from the listener.

Comment: here is my code   public function handle(Authenticated $event)
    {
        if ( $event->user->verified_email==0 )
        {
            return redirect('/logout');
        }
    }

Comment: `Auth::logout()` will log out the current user

Comment: how can i show the message to my login.blad  that sends from the LogAuthenticated  listener if ( $event->user->verified_email==0 )
        {
            Auth::logout();
            return redirect('/')->with('message', 'please verify your email.');
        }